Radical ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ and generalization?
I showed the following proposition in $\mathbb{Z}$. Does it seem fine to me, My question is if I can also use this same reasoning to show in the case of a commutative ring with a unit that is UFD. I think that the proof would be identified since everything irreducible is prime in a UFD.

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, prove that if $n = p_{1}^{k_{1}} p_{2}^{k_{2}} \cdots p_{r}^{k_{r}}$ where the $p_{i}$ are distinct primes, then $\sqrt{\langle n \rangle} = \langle p_{1} p_{2} \cdots p_{r} \rangle$.

$(\subset)$
If $y \in \sqrt{\langle n \rangle} \Rightarrow \exists m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $y^m \in \langle n \rangle$, then we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \Rightarrow y^m = p_1 \ldots p_r \cdot k \text{ with } k \in \mathbb{Z}, \\
& \Rightarrow p_i \mid y^m \text{ since they are distinct primes } \Rightarrow p_i \mid y \quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, r\}, \\
& \Rightarrow y = p_1 \ldots p_r \cdot l \text{ with } l \in \mathbb{Z}, \\
& \Rightarrow y \in \langle p_1, \ldots, p_r \rangle.
\end{aligned}
$$
$(\supset)$ we proceed analogously:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& y \in \langle p_1 \ldots p_r \rangle \Rightarrow \exists m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \text{ such that } y = p_1 \ldots p_r \cdot m, \\
& \Rightarrow \text{ let } n = \operatorname{lcm}(k_1, \ldots, k_r), \\
& \Rightarrow y^n = p_1^n \ldots p_r^n \cdot m^n, \\
& y^n = p_1^{k_1} \ldots p_r^{k_r} \cdot m^n \in \langle p_1 \ldots p_r \rangle.
\end{aligned}
$$

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Took me 1 minute of using site search to find the duplicate. Search terms: radical ideal UFD
